# example for shared element transition from activity to fragment

Tags: android

Android - Working on android shared element transition.Ive a activity A having list with images and a Fragment F .How to invoke shared transition for image in activity A to fragment F.

Comment: If Fragment F, as I guess, is inside Activity A, it should be an easy task.

Comment: 2 separate classes

Comment: OK. And WHERE is Fragment F physically appearing? Inside Activity A.

Comment: inside Activity A

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38974659/2590478)

Comment: hi did you find answer?

Comment: Any news? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented it first time with help of some basic tutorials.I can provide you two links.Hope you can also implement easily..

Check below Links -

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Shared-Element-Activity-Transition

http://www.androidauthority.com/using-shared-element-transitions-activities-fragments-631996/

Comment: it doesn't really describe how to pass shared element from activity to fragment

Comment: Looks like it's impossible. I couldn't achieve this in 3 hours.